# show custom date on xAxis in highstock lineseries

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have month end data for each month from february to december. On xAxis i want to show the day alond with month like 29.feb, 31.dec etc. i used tick interval and datetimelabelformats like this :

```
        xAxis : {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 3600*1000,//time in milliseconds
                    datetimelabelformats:{
                        day: '%e. %b',
                        month: '%b \'%y',
                        year: '%y'
                    }
                },
```

its showing date like 21.mar,25.Apr but i a not able to show the month end date like 31.mar. can anyone help? 
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aman25/m6rv5zkz/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting late, but I think you need to use `labels` like,

```
xAxis:{
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', this.value - 
                    3600000 //needed otherwise it will start from 1 date of month
                 );
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/m6rv5zkz/3/)**